# SQLAlchemy access session within Base class method?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm wanting to access a session from within my Base class's method without passing it in as an argument like this:

```py
class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'

    # id = ..., etc.
  
    def evaluate(self):  
        keywords = session.query(Keyword).all() # <- I want session already available.
        # Do something with keywords
```

How can I have the session ready to be used within a Base class's method?

Answer (score 2):

There's a pattern called a scoped session which is readily available in your Base class method.

Here's one approach:

Create a **Scoped Session** First, set up a scoped session at the start of your application. This session will be globally accessible throughout your application.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('your_database_url')
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
```

you can now use Session to interact with the database. The Session will refer to the same session throughout your application, making it easy to use.

```
class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'
    
    # id = ..., etc.

    def evaluate(self):
        # Use the session here
        keywords = Session.query(Keyword).all()
        # Do something with keywords
```

Just be careful to manage the session lifecycle properly to avoid issues like resource leaks or database locks.

Comment: I don't follow. Why does `scoped_session` solve anything about the issue being asked?

Comment: when you use Session() (the scoped_session I set up) inside the evaluate method, you're accessing the database session that's implicitly available to you. This removes the need to pass the session as an argument every time you want to access the database within your class methods. which i guess the question is !!